# Time invariance in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I write a MATLAB program that takes the given system described in terms input x(t) and output
y(t) relations is input and finds out whether it is time-invariant or not?

Comment: Testing for time invariance is not trivial. You could fit a system and see if various things are stationary for different time segments.

Comment: This sounds more like an algorithms problem than a MATLAB problem, someone here may be able to help though.

Comment: Sounds like something to ask at dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system):

> If the input signal x(t) produces an output y(t) then any time shifted
>   input, x(t + \delta), results in a time-shifted output y(t + \delta)

So all you have to do is input a signal and store its output. Then delay (i.e., shift) the input signal by some amount and then see if the output is a shifted version of the earlier one (with the shift being equal to the amount by which the input signal was shifted). With the information provided, it's impossible to say if there are certain classes of signals for which the above test would fail. However, if this is for homework or something, any old signal would probably do.

Comment: How to we take a signal as input? I mean everytime i do that it shows some kind of error.

Comment: The input signal would be an input argument to the function which models the system.